# Is it possible to make an object created in console persistent throughout the session?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, session, object, console

Goal: making a standalone modular JavaScript debuggin-utility (includes custom dom and event manipulation methods) to be used in the console (preferably Chrome) on any random sites of interests (with no backend access).

Usage: initially include module script directly via copy-paste to console or by creating a new `script` element pointing at `myhomepage.com/shortandeasytoremember.js` and call methods on the namespace from there on.

**Problem:** how to best make it persistent throughout the session on that webpage (so that I wouldn't need to reinclude it after every refresh) ?

Note: any additional browser compatibility is not required - as long as it works in the latest Chrome, it's all fine by me (but any effort in the compatibility department is always much appreciated for the sake of others). **IF YOU READ THIS IN A FAR FUTURE** and by then there exists a better solution than what is written down below, please take a moment to contribute with your superior knowledge.

What I currently have is an event listener on `window.unload` to save any state data to `localStorage` and a string to make it easier to reinclude the module after page reload using `eval(localStorage.getItem('loadMyNS'));`.

```
(function(ns, undefined){

    'use strict';

    //util methods on ns and few monkey patches for debugging ...

    var store = 'if(!window.MyNS){' +
        'var xyz9=document.createElement("script");' +
        'xyz9.src="http://myhomepage.com/shortandeasytoremember.js";' +
        'document.head.appendChild(xyz9);}';
    localStorage.setItem('loadMyNS', store);

    ns.save = function () {
        // and use localStorage for some more data 
        // to be used by other methods after page reload
    };

    window.addEventListener('unload', ns.save, false);

}(window.MyNS = window.MyNS || {}));
```

(browsers with no `localStorage` or `addEventListener` may benifit from [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-session-variable-library/))

I've also concidered using the same schema with `window.name` instead of `localStorage` ([as long as this still seems legid](http://www.sitepoint.com/cookieless-javascript-session-variables/)) just because writing `eval(window.name)` would take less typing ^^.

The trouble (one of them) I have with the "eval-script-tag-inclusion" is on the sites which block external non-https script sources. An ideal solution would be a globally accessible module which would live with state and methods included (and no initialization required after refresh) at least until I close the the window (or overwrite the ref ofc).

If that is currently absolutely not possible, a lesser solution yet still superior to my current code would suffice.

Comment: Did you consider implementing this as a custom Chrome plugin? They have access to more than what regular scripts can do. E.g. the "Lastpass" plugin seems to work in a similar way like you suggest.

Comment: I've used window.name for something similar with excellent results. It holds the value even after unload/url change

Comment: I've concidered a plugin option but in case I would like to use the script on client/not-my-own computers I wouldn't like to pollute their browsers.

Comment: Don't you think that if this was possible, this would introduce a security problem? I think this should not be possible exactly for that reason - hence the plugin approach or manual interaction like the bookmarklet trick they use in tools like [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) and [JSConsole](http://jsconsole.com/inject.html) - maybe the bookmarklet is as close as it gets or maybe those tools already suit your needs!